# Python - walk thought directories to process csv files and save them

Tags: python, csv

I want to walk through a list of `csv`files inside folders, perform some calculation (always the same) on each file, and save a new file for each one.

files have data structured in this manner:

```
"[Couplet 10 : Jul]
C'est 1.3.5 sur la plaque
Fais ton biz coupe ta plaque
C'est JU, JU , JUL qui débarque
Pour mes blancs , beurres et blacks
Passe moi un stunt pour voir si sa cabre
Embrouilles sur le sable , cocotiers sur la sappe
Je dors pas je suis tout pâle, je dis pas que je suis 2Pac
Je dis pas lui je vais le tuer si j'ai même pas 2 balles
C'est pour ceux qui XXX fais gaffe les shmits l'impact
Son anti B.D.H anti tapette",1

(...)
```

So far I have:

```
match = "^[\(\[].*?[\)\]]"
for d in directories:
        dir = os.path.join(data_dir, d)
        files_ = [os.path.join(dir, f) 
                      for f in os.listdir(dir) 
                      if f.endswith(".csv")]
        for f in files_:
            with open(f, 'rb') as f1, open('out.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
                reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter='\t')
                for item in list(reader):
                item = re.sub(match, ' ', item, flags=re.MULTILINE)      
                out_file.write(item)
```

but I get this traceback:

```
File "process_csv.py", line 75, in load_data
    item = re.sub(match, ' ', item, flags=re.MULTILINE)      
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

what is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: That looks pretty close to me.  Can you describe what is not behaving like you expect / error messages?

Comment: I've edited the question for you, adding the specific calculation and traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), re.sub expects third parameter as a string. But `list(reader)` returns list of lists with CSV fields, not strings. So you need to extract string from this lists and pass it to `re.sub`:

```
item = re.sub(match, ' ', item[0], flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

or whatever index you need to use in the calculations.

To understand it better, try:

```
test.csv: 
a 
b 
c

>>> f = open('test.csv')
>>> reader = csv.reader(f)
>>> list(reader)
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
```

**UPDATE**

To make it working on the real data example:

1. Set delimiter to `"` (by default) or change regex if quotes are important for processing.
2. Specify newline character as `''` when opening files. In python 2 `open` doesn't accept `newline` argument, use `io` package instead. `io` file opening has the same signature in general. Explanation from CSV package documentation:

> If newline='' is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use \r\n
>   linendings on write an extra \r will be added. It should always be
>   safe to specify newline='', since the csv module does its own
>   (universal) newline handling.

```
 with open(f, 'rb', newline='') as f1, open('out.csv', 'wb', newline='') as out_file:
    ...
```

3. It seems that substitution required for 1st column, so use item[0] for `sub`

Finally, corrected code:

```
import io

...

match = "^[\(\[].*?[\)\]]"
for d in directories:
    dir = os.path.join(data_dir, d)
    files_ = [os.path.join(dir, f) 
                  for f in os.listdir(dir) 
                  if f.endswith(".csv")]
    for f in files_:
        with io.open(f, 'rb', newline='') as f1, io.open('out.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
            reader = csv.reader(f1)
            writer = csv.writer(out_file) 
            for item in reader:
                writer.writerow([
                    re.sub(match, ' ', item[0], flags=re.MULTILINE),
                    item[1]
                ])
```

Comment: I have edited the question with the data to be changed and saved. could you be so kind as to edit your answer and contemplate the real example?

Comment: Can't find tab characters in your example. Am I right that the file contents only one column?

Comment: note the `1`, below. it'a a binary classifier for each text entry. comma  separates "lyrics" and classifier.

Comment: Clear, thanks, didn't noticed from mobile. I'll update the answer soon

Comment: is this for python `2.X`? I get `TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`and   `writer.write([
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'`. I have only `import csv`at the top of script

Comment: if I change `write` for `writerow`, it does not complain. but snippet still does not work...

Comment: I've changed example for python 2.x, check it again:)

Comment: brilliant. I had made it work with `csv.DictWriter()`, and                 `writer.writerows({'lyrics': re.sub(match, ' ', item[0], flags=re.MULTILINE),'classification': item[1]} for item in reader)`, but your solution is neat as well.